# Mathematical Induction for $n \geq 1$

Tags: induction

I want to prove, using mathematical induction, the following proposition:

$$1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+...+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\:\ge \sqrt{n}, \forall n \geq 1 \in \mathbb{N}$$

My thesis is:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}\ge \sqrt{n+1}, \forall n \geq 1 \in \mathbb{N}$$

I've proved the inequality for $n=1$, but after that I'm not being able to do the rest :/

Thank you for the help!

Comment: false............. The sum is larger than $\sqrt n,$ it is approximately $2 \sqrt n$ minus a modest constant

Comment: @WillJagy I'm sorry, it's now corrected!

Comment: What do you think you should do?  I don't see any of your writing or thinking, so I don't know what you're stuck on.  Have you even tried to show the base case ($n=2$)?

Comment: @EricTowers Yes, i've done that, and i'm stuck after that, I've study mathematical induction but i'm not understand how can i apply that for this example

Comment: @gammatester Yes, that's what i'm being asked for :P But you can also show that approach :)

Comment: What has to be proved in the inductive step? What can you use and where are you stuck?

Comment: @gammatester I need to prove that for (n+1) :)

Comment: Ok this is a start. Completely write down the inequality for $n+1$ and review your thesis.

Comment: @gammatester it's now in the problem description :)

Comment: No the correct 'thesis' would be
 $${\sqrt{n}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}\ge \sqrt{n+1}$$ or
 $${\sqrt{n}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}- \sqrt{n+1} \ge 0$$ 
write this as single fraction and continue.

Comment: @gammatester Ok, i've now write it as a single fraction, i got: $$\frac{\sqrt{n}\left(\sqrt{n+1}\right)+1}{\sqrt{n+1}}$$ but i still can't get this to look equal to $$\sqrt{n+1}$$

Comment: You forgot the third term, you should get
$$\frac{\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1}+1-(n+1)}{\sqrt{n+1}}$$
Can you show that the numerator is $\ge 0?$

Comment: @gammatester Ok, done. I've reached that expression. I know that for the smaller n (1), the numerator will be bigger than zero

Comment: Why only for 'smaller' $n?$ $\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1}$ is always $\ge n!$

Comment: @gammatester and in which way does that help me? o.O

Comment: It shows that
$$\sqrt{n}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} \ge \sqrt{n+1}$$
and this was the result needed to finish the incduction step.

Comment: Oh, i'm no understanding! Thank you very much for the amazing help!! :)

Comment: Your are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

For base cases $n=1$  we get that $1 \geq \sqrt{1}$

For $n=2$ we get that $1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \geq \sqrt{2}$.

Assume that $1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} +\cdots +\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \geq \sqrt{n}$.

And we want to prove that $1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} +\cdots +\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} \geq \sqrt{n+1}$

From the assumption step we know that $1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} +\cdots +\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \geq \sqrt{n}$

Substitute instead of $1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} +\cdots +\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ the $\sqrt{n}$.

To get $\sqrt{n}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} \geq \sqrt{n+1}$ (This what you need to prove).

Comment: thank you very much for the help! And how can I prove that last line? I've done the sum but it's giving me something really different that what we need to prove :O

Answer (score 1):

**The Inductive Step**

Since
$$
\begin{align}
\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n-1}
&=\frac1{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n-1}}\\
&\le\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\tag1
\end{align}
$$
we have
$$
\begin{align}
\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac1{\sqrt{k}}
&=\color{#C00}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac1{\sqrt{k}}}+\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\tag2\\
&\ge\color{#C00}{\sqrt{n-1}}+\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\tag3\\[9pt]
&\ge\sqrt{n}\tag4
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(2)$: expand sum
$(3)$: inductive hypothesis
$(4)$: apply $(1)$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sqrt n\;+\frac {1}{\sqrt {n+1}}\geq \sqrt {n+1}\iff \frac {1}{\sqrt {n+1}}\;\geq \sqrt {n+1}-\sqrt n=$$ $$=(\sqrt {n+1}-\sqrt n)\cdot \frac {\sqrt {n+1}+\sqrt n}{\sqrt {n+1}+\sqrt n}=\frac {1}{\sqrt {n+1}+\sqrt n}\iff$$ $$\iff \frac {1}{\sqrt {n+1}}\geq \frac {1}{\sqrt {n+1}+\sqrt n}\;.$$

Answer (score 0):

For $n \ge1 $, we have  $$n \ge n-1 + \frac1{n+1}$$
$$\iff n \ge n+1-2 + \frac1{n+1}$$ 
$$\Rightarrow n \ge (\sqrt{n+1} - \frac1{\sqrt{n+1}})^2$$
$$\Rightarrow \sqrt{n} \ge \sqrt{n+1} - \frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}$$

Now $\sqrt{1} \ge 1$. Assume $\sum_{r=1}^n \frac1{\sqrt{r}} \ge \sqrt{n}$.

Then $$\sum_{r=1}^n \frac1{\sqrt{r}} \ge \sqrt{n} \ge \sqrt{n+1} - \frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}$$

$$\Rightarrow \sum_{r=1}^{n+1} \frac1{\sqrt{r}} \ge \sqrt{n+1}$$

Hence , by induction , $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \sum_{r=0}^n \frac1{\sqrt{r}} \ge \sqrt{n}$.